# Golang: convertor function

Tags: string, go, type-conversion, converters

We have some structure `S`. Is it possible to make a converter so that the expression

```
s := S(a_string)
```

began to compile, where `a_string` is actually a `string`.

Comment: (s := S(a_string))

Answer (score 1):

The allowed conversions are listed in [Spec: Conversions](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Conversions). There's a section for *"Conversions to and from a string type"*. Only those are allowed, you can't "extend" or change the behavior of conversions.

You may however always write a *function* that takes a `string` and returns a value of type `S`.

```
func Parse(s string) S {
    var r S
    // Parsing logic
    return r
}
```

Using it is / looks like the same as a conversion:

```
s := Parse(a_string)
```